# How to Pass Values From a DataGridView to another Form textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i could transfer the values put now the problem is in the switch cases i make switch to be able to transfer data to several form put only the form opened put i can not do that in switch it goes to default case on running so the problem is on (FORMID) how do i use switch case Correctly here
this is my form1 code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f2.setParent(this);
        f2.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.Show();
        f2.Activate();
    }
}
```

}

and this form 2 code :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public int FORMID = 0;
    private Form1 f1;
    private Form3 f3;
    DataTable dt;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void load_table()
    {
        string constring = "Data Source =.; initial Catalog = business; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from T_AKARAT_BUILDING_TP", CN);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            bsource.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            sda.Update(dt);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        load_table();
    }

    public void setParent(Form1 parentValue)
    {
        f1 = parentValue;
    }

    public void setParent(Form3 parentValue)
    {
        f3 = parentValue;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (FORMID)
        {
            case 1:

        f1.textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex][0].ToString();
        f1.textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex][1].ToString();
        this.Hide();
        break;
            case 2:
        f3.textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex][0].ToString();
        f3.textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex][1].ToString();
        this.Hide();
        break;
            default:
        MessageBox.Show("plz select");
        break;
        }
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

}

I set text boxes modifiers public in form 2 but this code does not work & i do not know what is missing or wrong here hope to help me

hope some one to correct my code not giving examples please

Comment: you can place a datatable as an argument in form2 constructor,then in form1 you call it passing the datatable.

Comment: even with a variable of form2 in your form1 you cant set the text of your textboxes because their access modifiers are set to private,only if you change it to public,which might not be best option.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use the class
create a class1.cs
code in class for example :

```
class Class1
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public Class1 FirstName(string firstname)
    {
        this.firstName = firstname;
        return this;
    }
    public Class1 LastName(string lastname)
    {
        this.lastName = lastname;
        return this;
    }
}
```

code in form1 :

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c.firstName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    c.lastName = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```

Now you can use this code for all programs

Example on another form:

```
label1.text = c.firstName;
label2.text = c.lastName;
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

another way is that, define two public variable in form2 and this value in form1 set to those variables then in form2 Enter Event set those variables to textboxes

Comment: aref mohammadi,could you please an example

Comment: i put my full code , i could transfer the values put now the problem is in the switch cases i make switch to be able to transfer data to several form put only the form opened put i can not do that in switch it goes to default case on running so the problem is on (FORMID) how do i use switch case Correctly here

Answer (score 0):

Assigning value to the textboxes should work the way you have it.  However your code isn't calling FDAS.Show.

Also your closing form1, therefore you'll probably have to declare a new form1 to set the parent

Comment: @user2536447  when you get your double-click event you are not getting any specific row,cell....its just reacting to you double-clicking the datagrid.with for example RowHeaderMouseClick you click the header and get that row index,easier to filter data.

Answer (score 0):

try it in cellmousedoubleclick event,the names i put are example only you can change to your own:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
       Form2 f2 = new Form2();
       f2.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
       f2.Show();
}
```

this will do if access modifiers of textbox are public.

This 2 examples will place your 2 textboxes text to the,1º example - column values -,2º example - row values.

```
        private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {

            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
            f2.textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString();
            f2.textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
            f2.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this .. FDAS must declared first as Form class

```
public void setParent()
{
    FDAS = form2;
}
```

Comment: i put my full code , i could transfer the values put now the problem is in the switch cases i make switch to be able to transfer data to several form put only the form opened put i can not do that in switch it goes to default case on running so the problem is on (FORMID) how do i use switch case Correctly here

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not say which line of code is causing the "object reference not set" exception. And, since we can't see all of your code, we have to guess as to where the problem might be.

When you instantiate Form2, you have to set it's MdiParent property. And yet, you're using that MdiParent property in your Form2 constructor (and this isn't correct either):

```
public form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // neither one of the following lines make any sense, get rid of them
    //form1.setParent(this);
    //form1.MdiParent = this.MdiParent; 
}
```

You don't show the code where you're instantiating Form2 in Form1, but it needs to be done like this:

```
// somewhere in Form1
Form2 FDAS = new Form2();
FDAS.MdiParent = this;
```

Also, because form1 is an MdiParent, I think you'll also get errors when you .Close() it, so I'm not sure why you're doing that!

Comment: Bonnie DeWitt, when i put your code on form1 i got error FDAS is afield but is used like atype

Comment: Could you show us where that error is occurring? Because the code that I showed should not give you that error, so it must be left over from some of your original code, perhaps some that we haven't seen here yet.

Comment: Bonnie , i put my full code , i could transfer the values put now the problem is in the switch cases i make switch to be able to transfer data to several form put only the form opened put i can not do that in switch it goes to default case on running so the problem is on (FORMID) how do i use switch case Correctly here

Comment: Wow, it gets confusing when the original post gets totally modified. Anyway, it seems to me that you're not setting FORMID anywhere, so it remains as 0 (hence the reason why your switch goes to the default case).

Comment: this true i put break point on the code and FORMID value does not change but i do not know how to set FORMID on other forms to make it work on switch case

Comment: I don't know ... maybe in the setParent() method?